# vb.net dropdown list cannot pop up the details after I did selection

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

what I want to do is after I select the name from the dropdown list, the details which are related with the user can pop up in the textboxes. I created a view at sql alreaday called VEditUser. But after I run the code, try catch always tell incorrect syntax near " = ".  Can somebody tell me where is wrong?

```vb
Dim MyConnection As New SqlConnection
Dim Command As New SqlCommand
Dim Datareader As SqlDataReader

Try

'Create a connection to the SQL server
MyConnection.ConnectionString = "server=(local);database=dbSQL1;Trusted_Connection=yes"
MyConnection.Open()
Command.CommandText = "SELECT strFirstName, strLastName, strAddress, strCity, intStateID, strZipcode, strEmail, strCellPhone, intServiceGroupID, intRoleID, intStatusID, strLoginName FROM VEditUser = " & ddlCustomer.SelectedValue

Command.Connection = MyConnection
Datareader = Command.ExecuteReader

Try
    If Datareader.HasRows Then

        Datareader.Read()

        txtFirstName.Text = Datareader.Item("strFirstName")
        txtLastName.Text = Datareader.Item("strLastName")
        txtAddress.Text = Datareader.Item("strAddress")
        txtCity.Text = Datareader.Item("strCity")
        dpdState.Text = Datareader.Item("intStateID")
        txtZipcode.Text = Datareader.Item("strZipcode")
        txtEmail.Text = Datareader.Item("strEmail")
        txtCellPhone.Text = Datareader.Item("strCellPhone")
        dpdServiceGroup.Text = Datareader.Item("intServiceGroupID")
        dpdRole.Text = Datareader.Item("intRoleID")
        dpdStatus.Text = Datareader.Item("intStatusID")
        txtUserName.Text = Datareader.Item("strLoginName")
    End If

Catch ex As Exception

End Try

MyConnection.Close() 'Close the connection.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer is that you are missing the `where` from your Sql:

change:

```
Command.CommandText = "SELECT strFirstName, strLastName, strAddress, strCity, intStateID, strZipcode, strEmail, strCellPhone, intServiceGroupID, intRoleID, intStatusID, strLoginName FROM VEditUser = " & ddlCustomer.SelectedValue
```

to

```
Command.CommandText = "SELECT strFirstName, strLastName, strAddress, strCity, intStateID, strZipcode, strEmail, strCellPhone, intServiceGroupID, intRoleID, intStatusID, strLoginName FROM VEditUser WHERE strLoginName  = " & ddlCustomer.SelectedValue
```

For example.  If `strLoginName` is not the value in the dropdown then replace as appropriate

The slightly longer answer is that you should be protecting yourself from [Sql Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) by always sanitising your inputs, and using parameterized queries.  In the example you have provided you can achieve this by using the following:

```
Command.CommandText = "SELECT strFirstName, strLastName, strAddress, strCity, intStateID, strZipcode, strEmail, strCellPhone, intServiceGroupID, intRoleID, intStatusID, strLoginName FROM VEditUser WHERE strLoginName = @customer"

cmd.Parameters.Add("@customer", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ddlCustomer.SelectedValue

Command.Connection = MyConnection
```

Comment: Thank you!! My textboxes worked! But I noticed that all my dropdown lists don't show anything. like this status dropdown list, should I change dpdStatus.Text = Datareader.Item("intStatusID") to dpdStatus.SelectValue = Datareader.Item("intStatusID")?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the form and knowing if they are databound etc but that sounds like a good start.  If they are dropdowns then you will need to find the item with the corresponding value, not just set the text

Comment: Your dropdown list need to have another data bind for the data.

Comment: I actually really don't think the records are databound.. But how I supposed to do to let the dropdown list can databind from the view from sql?